# Use of the degree variable in an MSOL formula

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, treewidth

I am working on giving an MSOL formula for an NP-hard problem; this proves that the problem is linear-time solvable on bounded treewidth graphs. Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, the problem would be to find a subset $S \subseteq V$ such that each vertex of degree at least three has at least two neighbors and at most three neighbours in $S$. The MSOL formula for the problem is: 
$\exists S \subseteq V:\forall v \in V\setminus d(v) \leq 2: ((\exists {u_1, u_2} \in S) \land (u_1 \in N(v)) \land (u_2 \in N(v)))$ $\land ((\exists u_3 \in S) \land ((u_3 \in N(v) \lor (u_3 \notin N(v))))$ $\land ((\forall u \in S \setminus \{u_1,u_2, u_3\}) \land (u \notin N(v)))$ where $d(v)$ indicates the degree of $v$.

1. Is this a valid MSOL formula? can i make use of $d(v)$ in the formula?
2. If not, how can i modify it in such a way that the formula solves the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's _check my homework_

Comment: My main concern is whether or not $d(v)$ can be used in the formula. Please clarify this or at least point me to some references on this. @PålGD

Answer (score 1):

> main concern is whether or not $d(v)$ can be used in the formula

The answer to this is *no*.

However, if you want to ask whether the degree is (equal to, at least, at most) some fixed constant $c$, then you can make a formula like this:

$$d(v) \geq c \; \triangleq \; \exists u_1 \exists u_2 \cdots \exists u_c \; vu_1 \in E \land vu_2 \in E \land \cdots \land vu_c \in E \land u_1 \neq u_2 \land \cdots \land u_{c-1} \neq u_c$$